# How to protect route from user to access without making payment?

Tags: reactjs

I have a system where I am charging clients. After every successful payment, I take them to the receipt page using

> history.push('/receipt/:orderid')

Now I want to know how can I make it protected? I do not users to access it like `xyz.com/receipt/321` from the checkout page without making payment. Currently, any logged in user can type the URL and access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your protected routes in another react component.
let's name this component `ProtectedRoutes` so now we can dive into code.

**ProtectedRoutes.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function ProtectedRoutes({ children, location }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    //this is where you send a request to the server to check if the user has made the payment
    //and if the response was false redirect the user using history.replace()
  }, [location.pathname])
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Router.js**

```
<ProtectedRoutes>
  <Route path="/product" exact component={Product} />
</ProtectedRoutes>
```

By using this concept you can protect your routes easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-router-guards](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-guards) npm package, which provides a middleware API for **React Router**, allowing you to *perform complex logic* between the call for navigation and the final render of a route.

`$ npm install react-router-guards`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest: on the order page, you check the token, if the user has permission, send data to the user.